# Run multiple functions based on a SINGLE form submission (method="post") using Node-express

Tags: html, forms, node.js, mongoose

I am looking to perform multiple actions upon receiving HTML(or EJS) form content using the POST method. I am using Node express, mongoose & mongoDB. Each of the below POST responses work individually but i am unsure how to proceed in updating multiple databases based on ONE SINGLE form submission.

```
// insert into passport db
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', 
{
    successRedirect : '/index', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));
//insert into my database here
```

[the content of in the second function is unimportant as that is working fine and has been stripped down for simplification.]

```
app.post('/signup', function( req, res )
{
    new UserDB(
    {
        user_id : req.body.content,
        first_name : req.body.fname,
    }).save( function( err, mySite, count )
    {
        res.redirect( '/index' );
    });
});
```

I have tried redirecting but the form content is not accessible after the redirect so only the first function stores the data (ie. only 1 database is filled).

How would i run both functions within

```
app.post('/signup',..... 
{
    ...
});
```

?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making one function the callback of the other. This is easy because each function maintains the same Connect middleware signature, `function(req, res, next)`, where `req` and `res` are the request and response objects created and manipulated by the application, and `next` is the next function to call at the end of the current function's execution.

According to [the official documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/), `passport.authenticate()` is a normal piece of middleware. All you need to do is specify the middleware you want to be called next. Express queues middleware functions in the order in which you pass them into `app.post`. You can do something like this:

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    failureRedirect : '/signup',
    failureFlash : true
}),
function(req, res) {
    new UserDB({
        user_id : req.body.content,
        first_name : req.body.fname,
    }).save(function(err, mySite, count) {
        res.redirect('/index');
    });
});
```

Middleware is an extremely powerful feature of the Express framework and possibly the single most important one to master. [This guide](http://stephensugden.com/middleware_guide/) would be a great next step if you want to learn more.